# Cannot connect from one AMI ec2 instance to another

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I can connect from my windows PC using putty to my AMI E2C linux instances but I cannot ssh from one instance to another. I get the following error message, I have just copied the last part of the error message:

```
debug1: Found key in /home/ec2-user/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

the security group for all servers has SSH open to source `0.0.0.0`

I have tried creating new ssh keys, ssh-keygen -t -rsa, and copying and pasting the content of the .pub file to /.ssh/authorized_keys file on the other server. But it still does not work.

I have tried copying contents of both files to the other server to /.ssh keeping the same file name and running chmod 600 again both files. But still it does not work.

Comment: I cannot believe it, I have been stuck on this issue for 2 days.
On closer inspection of the ID_RSA file I created on the server I wanted to connect to, which I had a copy and pasted the public key from the other server, did not have all of the key pasted. The copy and paste function missed off the first few characters of the key. 
Once I put those in the ssh connection worked!

Answer (score 1):

I cannot believe it, I have been stuck on this issue for 2 days.

On closer inspection of the ID_RSA file I created on the server I wanted to connect to, which I had a copy and pasted the public key from the other server, did not have all of the key pasted.  The copy and paste function missed off the first few characters of the key.

Once I put those in the ssh connection worked!

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you're creating key with non-standard name.

This is how I do in this case:

server #1:

```bash
$ ls -la ~/
...
drwx------ 2 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Mar 16 00:27 .ssh
...

$ ls -l ~/.ssh
total 12
-rw------- 1 ec2-user ec2-user  731 Mar  3 16:05 authorized_keys
-rw-r--r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user 2220 Mar 17 11:39 known_hosts
-rw------- 1 ec2-user ec2-user 3326 Mar  4 00:48 roman.pem
```

server #2:

```bash
$ ls -la ~/
...
drwx------ 2 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Mar 17 12:10 .ssh
...

$ ls -l ~/.ssh
total 4
-rw------- 1 ec2-user ec2-user 731 Mar 17 12:10 authorized_keys
```

`authorized_keys` has only one record and is identical to the one from server #1

This is the command I use for connection from server #1 to server #2:

```
$ ssh -v <server#2-ip> -i ~/.ssh/roman.pem
```

As you can see, I use `-i` to specify full path to key name.

---

**Update:**

Also, custom key could be added to ssh-agent on server #1: `ssh-add ~/.ssh/roman.pem` in order to skip `-i` switch.